# Postfix SMTP lookup in /etc/services failed

Tags: postfix, smtp

I am running a `postfix` server on `Ubuntu 16.04`. Probably related to an update the mail server did not work anymore.

The log tells: `postfix/master[4590]: fatal: 127.0.0.1:smtp: Servname not supported for ai_socktype`

This usually means, that the port lookup for the service failed because of missing entries in `/etc/services`. But in my case, there is not missing anything.

Replacing the smtp with "25" in `/etc/postfix/master.cf`

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
```

lets the mail server run.

My `/etc/services` looks like this:

```
smtp            25/tcp          mail
smtp            25/udp          mail
```

File permissions are 644. Any ideas why the lookup does not work?